# Android Studio "Cause: module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @413d1baf" error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When I open an old project on Android Studio, this error pops up and I can't fix it. Just because the gradle version is not compatible with java, I updated it to the desired version, the error was fixed, but now this error has appeared. Any ideas on how I can fix it?

*Cause: module java.base does not open java.lang to unnamed module @413d1baf*

*Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 20.0.2. It's recommended to use Gradle 4.8.1.

Possible solution:

- Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project*

First of all, this error message appeared. To fix this I made Gradle version 4.8.1 from 4.4 but then I got the error I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?